# Make radio buttons "checkable": HTML

Tags: html, radio-button

How do I make radio buttons operate more like a check box?  I need the function of a radio button, but it needs to be able to be de-selected.

Comment: Do you need to have more than one checkbox selected at a time?

Comment: No.  The radio buttons need to work just like radio buttons do--they just need be be de-selectable.

Comment: You might want to include some information about the context in which this radio button lives. It is HTML? WinForms? Swing?

Comment: It might help to tell everyone your platform and/or programming environment...

Comment: You should confirm what environment you're talking about.  I assume you mean html, but this question could refer to anything.

In Adobe Flex we could easily use a checkbox and tell it to use the radio button skin instead.  I'm sure you're not talking about Flex though.

Comment: @MYYN, check-boxes don't exclude another option when selected, do they?
@Adam, HTML.

Comment: Kevin - I retagged it for you, but you might want to edit the question yourself to make this easier to answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually this is accomplished by adding another option, "None".  Users would not expect that clicking a selected radio button will deselect it since that's not normal behavior.

Another option, not often used anymore, is a "clear" button.  I don't like this option though.

Comment: +1 don't change the basic behaviour of basic form elements. It greatly confuses the user.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a "none" option, or create a javascript button to unselect every radio button. I wonder if the onclick event of a radio button react if it is already selected...

Answer (score 2):

You could add an onClick function to each radio button that would de-select it if it was clicked while selected (haven't tried it, but it seems reasonable). This is really unexpected behavior for most users though - I think the other answers suggesting a 'None' option are better.

EDIT: Just for fun, I tried this out. It works. My code is pretty cheesy - done just for a quickie test.

```
<script>
  var x = false;
</script>

<input type="radio" value="test 1" name="1" onmousedown="if (this.checked) { x = true; }" onclick="if (x) {this.checked = false; x = false; return true;}" />1
<input type="radio" value="test 2" name="1" onmousedown="if (this.checked) { x = true; }" onclick="if (x) {this.checked = false; x = false; return true;}" />2
<input type="radio" value="test 3" name="1" onmousedown="if (this.checked) { x = true; }" onclick="if (x) {this.checked = false; x = false; return true;}" />3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "none" option as suggested by others.  If that is not acceptable your other options are:

1. Check boxes with logic to accept only one selection.
2. A list box that only allows single selections.